# Using scipy.optimize.minimize with a discrete Gaussian kernel

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I am using scipy.optimize.minimize to try to determine the optimal parameters of a probability density function (PDF). My PDF involves a discrete Gaussian kernel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space_implementation#The_discrete_Gaussian_kernel).

In theory, I know the average value of the PDF (where the PDF should be centered on). So if I were to calculate the expectation value of my PDF, I should recover the mean value that I already know. My PDF is sampled at discrete values of n (which must never be negative and should start at 0 to make any physical sense), and I am trying to determine the optimal value of t (the "scaling factor") to recover the average value of the PDF (which again, I already know ahead of time).

My minimal working example to determine the optimal "scaling factor" t is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                                      

import numpy as np
from scipy.special import iv
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def discrete_gaussian_kernel(t, n):
    return np.exp(-t) * iv(n, t)

def expectation_value(t, average):

    # One constraint is that the starting value                                                                                                                                                             
    # of the range over which I sample the PDF                                                                                                                                                              
    # should be 0.                                                                                                                                                                                          

    # Method 1 - This seems to give good, consistent results                                                                                                                                                
    int_average = int(average)
    ceiling_average = int(np.ceil(average))
    N = range(int_average - ceiling_average + 1,
              int_average + ceiling_average + 2)

    # Method 2 - The multiplicative factor for 'end' is arbitrary.                                                                                                                                          
    #            I should in principle be able make end be as large as                                                                                                                                      
    #            I want since the PDF goes to zero for large values of n,                                                                                                                                   
    #            but this seems to impact the result and I do now know why.                                                                                                                                 
    #start = 0                                                                                                                                                                                              
    #end = 2 * int(average)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    #N = range(start, end)                                                                                                                                                                                  

    return np.sum([n * discrete_gaussian_kernel(t, n - average) for n in N])

def minimize_function(t, average):
    return average - expectation_value(t, average)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    average = 8.33342
    #average = 7.33342                                                                                                                                                                                      

    solution = minimize(fun = minimize_function,
                        x0 = 1,
                        args = average)

    print(solution)
    t = solution.x[0]
    print('          solution t =', t)
    print('       given average =', average)
    print('recalculated average =', expectation_value(t, average))
```

I have two problems with my minimal working example:

1) The code works OK for some values of what I choose for the variable "average." One example of this is when the value is 8.33342. However, the code does not work for other values, for example 7.33342. In this case, I get

```
 RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

so I was thinking that maybe scipy.optimize.minimize is choosing a bad value for t (like a large negative number). I am confident that this is the problem since I have printed out the value of t in the function expectation_value, and t becomes increasingly negative. So I would like to add bounds to the possible values of what "t" can take ("t" should not be negative). Looking at the documentation of scipy.optimize.minimize, there is a bounds keyword argument. So I tried:

```
solution = minimize(fun = minimize_function,
                    x0 = 1,
                    args = average,
                    bounds = ((0, None)))
```

but I get the error:

```
 ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds
```

I searched for this error on stackoverflow, and there are some other threads, but I did not find any helpful. How can I set a bound successfully?

2) My other question has to do with scipy.optimize.minimize being sensitive to the range over which I calculate the expectation value. For an average value of

```
 average = 8.33342
```

and the method of calculating the range as

```
# Method 1 - This seems to give good, consistent results                                                                                                                                                
int_average = int(average)
ceiling_average = int(np.ceil(average))
N = range(int_average - ceiling_average + 1,
          int_average + ceiling_average + 2)
```

the "recalculated average" is 8.3329696426. But for the other method (which has a very similar range),

```
# Method 2 - The multiplicative factor for 'end' is arbitrary.                                                                                                                                          
#            I should in principle be able make end be as large as                                                                                                                                      
#            I want since the PDF goes to zero for large values of n,                                                                                                                                   
#            but this seems to impact the result and I do now know why.                                                                                                                                 
start = 0
end = 2 * int(average)
N = range(start, end)
```

the "recalculated average" is 8.31991111857. The ranges are similar in each case, so I don't know why there is such a large change, especially since I what my recalculated average to be as close as possible to the true average. And if I were to extend the range to larger values (which I think is reasonable since the PDF goes to zero there),

```
start = 0
end = 4 * int(average)
N = range(start, end)
```

the "recalculated average" is 9.12939372912, which is even worse. So is there a consistent method to calculate the range so that the reconstructed average is always as close as possible to the true average? The scaling factor can take on any value so I would think scipy.optimize.minimize should be able to find a scaling factor to get back the true average exactly.

Comment: FYI: If you include `from scipy.special import ive`, you can replace `np.exp(-t) * iv(n, t)` with `ive(n, t)`; see [`scipy.special.ive`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ive.html).  This will help with the overflow, but it won't necessarily fix other problems that you may be having.